# How to remove columns CSV Notepad++ / RegEx?

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

```
a,b,c,d
aaa,2.15,100.15,-
bbb,3.16,215.16,-
ccc,4.10,365.18,-
```

I want to remove

```
2.15,
3.16,
4.10,
```

and

```
,-
,-
,-
```

I want to remove columns b + d

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORJVU.jpg)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Lsc.jpg)

---

,[\w].*,[\w].

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with a regex, I think it replaces the whole match. If all columns have the same width, you can select it with Alt + mouse. If not, I would do it with Excel.

Comment: Please format the post so it is readable. Use the markdown available. Post an example of what you want the CSV to look like before and after.

Comment: You can try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/oM8jL3/1).

Comment: You said rows, but they are columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture everything but the two columns.
(*Edit: added `\r\n` so don't span lines*)

X = Before col 1: = b-1
Y = Before col 2: = d-1 - X - 1

Find:
`(?m)^((?:[^,\r\n]*,){X})[^,\r\n]*,((?:[^,\r\n]*,){Y})[^,\r\n]*(.*)`

Replace:
`$1$2$3`

Example -

X = 2-1 (Col 2) = 1
Y = 4-1 - X - 1 (Col 4) = 1

Regex: `(?m)^((?:[^,\r\n]*,){1})[^,\r\n]*,((?:[^,\r\n]*,){1})[^,\r\n]*(.*)`

---

Or, if this is a 1-off thing, use

`(?m)^([^,\r\n]*,)[^,\r\n]*,([^,\r\n]*).*`

Replace `$1$2`

Which just eliminates column's 2 and 4.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I couldn't make it work either in regex101 or Notepad++. It matches nothing.

Comment: @sln **Thank you** I really appreciate your help ^^

Comment: Oh, I'm only (most of the time) posting stuff that works from testing. What specifically doesn't work @Andrew, post a link to something if you can. I use my own offline tester/analyzer.

Comment: @Andrew - The input was incorrect, try here: https://regex101.com/r/rP4xM2/2 or here: https://regex101.com/r/rP4xM2/3

Comment: But that's not what moon90 posted as the source input, nor is the output he expects.

Comment: @Andrew - Did you do the X,Y calculation and substitution as mentioned?

Comment: No, I just realized what you tried to do. I find your explanation really hard to understand (I wasn't sure they were subtractions, columns layout or what). Anyway, with this regex you don't validate anything about the format (for that I would simply use LukStorm's option),  and you are also removing everything after the `,-`.

Comment: @Andrew - Your welcome to debate the difference between  this `[^,\r\n]*,` and this `.*?,` One thing is for sure, validation is done on the content in the first form but not the second. The second form can match multiple comma's depending on the sub-expresions around it.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ solution:

- Find what: `^(.*?),.*?,(.*?),.*$`
- Replace with : `$1,$2`
- Search mode : Regular expression (without the `. matches newline`)

The regex will put the first and 3rd column into capture groups.
Which are used in the replace.

Comment: **Thank you** very much for your help  ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just search for this:

```
(\w+),\d+\.?\d*,(\d+\.?\d*),-
```

And replace with this:

```
$1,$2
```

End result:

```
a,b,c,d
aaa,100.15
bbb,215.16
ccc,365.18
```

It supports numbers with or without decimals, any number of digits. You may have to modify it if the first column has special characters.

Comment: That means you helped me, haha. You should mark some answer as accepted if it helped you. If you want to validate the data is in the expected format, use this regex. If you only care about the number of columns, you can use LukStorms'.

Comment: I'm Sorry : Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: But did you use sln's option and it worked? It didn't work for me with your input values.

Comment: Yes, It Worked . ALL Codes Worked .. Good ^^