# How to sort data 2 columns CSV / Notepad++?

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I want to sort data column ( b ) in Notepad++

```
a,b
aaa,1.4
bbb,1.2
ccc,1.5
ddd,1.9
eee,1.7
fff,1.8
ggg,1.3
```

[image: img1]

Like This :

```
a,b
ddd,1.9
fff,1.8
eee,1.7
ccc,1.5
aaa,1.4
ggg,1.3
bbb,1.2
```

[image: img2]

Comment: Are you opposed to importing it in excel and sorting it there?

Comment: Yes , big file , I can't sort data in excel or google docs

Comment: I am not aware of any internal mechanism in Notepad++, but someone may prove me wrong. In your case, I'd process the file with python or some other programming language. How many records is the file?

Comment: More than 900000 line / row .
80 MB

Comment: Later versions of excel could handle that. Or Access.

Comment: Does notepad even sort lines? If it does, it's too bad it can't use a simple regex per line with a capture value to use for comparison. Ever thought of using Perl to do this?

Comment: It requires time , And In some Lines not completed @MattCremeens Cremeens

Comment: I agree it takes time, but it could be as simple as dumping it into an access table and run `select a, b from mytable order by b desc;` You could even export it back to a file if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Matt Cremeens / sln

Answer (score 2):

### 1 - Switch position of column

Search :

```
^([^,]*\,)([^,].*)
```

Replace :

```
$2,$1
```

### 2 - Download new version Notepad++ 6.5.2

[Notepad++ 6.5.2 sort data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPbzs.png)

[Img Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiVky.png)

Thanks For

@Wiktor Stribiżew : [Switch word postions in Notepad ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223508/switch-word-postions-in-notepad)

@Franck Dernoncourt : https://superuser.com/questions/724176/sort-text-by-value-in-notepad

@sln : @Andrew : @LukStorms
[How to remove columns CSV Notepad++ / RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254901/how-to-remove-columns-csv-notepad-regex)

@Matt Cremeens

Comment: You should modify your question for adding new details.

Answer (score 1):

Install TextFX plugin .

Select the column by <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the left mouse button to highlight what will be selected.

Go to the menu dropdown of `TextFX` Tool menu option to sort by columns:

***TextFX - TextFX Tools - Sort lines case sensitive (at column)***

And your list will be sorted

[Sorted list Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L8GL.png)

[Sorted list Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkO8e.png)

[Sorted list Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqk9b.png)

Comment: What if the column can't be selected by `Alt` + `Left Mouse`?